# Bootstrap's 4.6 popover stops scrolling and is still visible when element reaches boundaries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with popover visualization using Bootstrap 4.6

In this minimum example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body style="background-color: cadetblue; height:1000px">

<header style="height: 100px">

</header>
<section style="overflow-y: auto; height: 500px; background-color: cornsilk;">
    

<div style="height: 1000px" > </div>
<div id="test">
<button type="button" 
    data-placement="top" 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    title="Blah" 
    data-content="Bleh Bleh">Blih</button>
</div>
<script>
$("button").popover({})
</script>
<div style="height: 1000px" > </div>



  
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

the popover is correctly shown when the button is visible inside the scroll:

[Popover shows ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEt9G.png)

But if I scroll and the button "passes" the "cadetblue" zones the popover, instead of keeping scrolling and eventually stopping being visible stays on the top / bottom boundary:

[Popover stays in the "upper limit" when scrolling the section down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pfcn.png)

[Popover stays in the "lower limit" when scrolling the section up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yWAd.png)

I've tried fiddling with the `container`, `boundary` and `fallbackPlacement` options as some answers to similar problems suggest, but to no avail. From what I've been investigating in this and other sites the popover visualization in Bootstrap 4.6 is a tricky question, but since this is such a simple problem I'm sure that I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 0):

At long last I found a solution, using what's commented in [this issue](https://github.com/floating-ui/floating-ui/issues/52).

Apparently, Popper (the library used by Bootstrap to show the Popovers) toggles the attribute "x-out-of-boundaries" on the popover whenever the element that triggers the popover exits its boundaries.

Thus, the solution is to add a css rule similar to

```
        .popover[x-out-of-boundaries]{
            display: none;
        }
```

to hide the popover when the element stops being visible.